# mongodb on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I know this question was asked several times, but I have tried all the mentioned solutions and it did not work. I have installed mongodb as described in the mongodb docs, 10gen package. I have checked the permissions on both the log and data folder and they are set to mongodb.

This is the logfile

```
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.511 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21678 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=copperdroid
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.511 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.511 [initandlisten] git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.511 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.511 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.511 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.513 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.513 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.550 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.550 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.551 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0 secs
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.551 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.0, filling with zeroes...
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.551 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.553 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Wed Oct  2 13:33:52.553 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Which does not seem to show any issue. When I try to start the mongoconsole I get

```
Wed Oct  2 13:37:32.769 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
```

Comment: try to remove lock file `sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

Comment: I have tried that too.

Comment: are you sure that you 've started mongodb? `sudo service mongodb start`

Comment: Yeah, also run ps aux | mongo: mongodb  21678  0.2  0.1 348140 38664 ?        Ssl  13:33   0:03 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Comment: There could be some kind of firewall that prevent connection. Try to start `mongod` on port which you absolutely sure isn't blocked.

Comment: Now it is complaining about the permissions for locale.ns. I saw that the ownership belongs to root, shall I change that?

Comment: Ports are open by the way.